# Python creating 2D array

Tags: python, list

```
num1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
num2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

arr1 = [[0]*(len(num2)+1)]*(len(num1)+1)
arr2 = [[0 for _ in range(len(num2)+1)] for _ in range(len(num1)+1)]
```

I get a different answer when I define arr1 and arr2.
Aren't arr1 and arr2 create the same 2D array?

Comment: If you fix your typo (`nums` to `num`) I got the same answer for both, a 6 times 6 2d list filled with zeros. The internal function is different because in `arr1` all sub lists point to the same ID in memory while `arr2` all sublists are unique. (for example `arr1[0][0] = 1` will result that each first element of all sublists will be 1.

Comment: You have `num1` and `num2`, but then use `nums1` and `nums2`, which are probably arrays you defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same. `arr1` is a list with `(len(nums1)+1)` references to the same list `[0]*(len(nums2)+1)`. So when you modify an element in one of them, all references will see this change as well.

For example,

```
>>> arr1[0][0] += 1
>>> print(arr1)
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

`arr2` doesn't suffer from this problem because it has `len(nums1)+1` distinct lists:

```
>>> arr2[0][0] += 1
>>> print(arr2)
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to see the difference is to use a random number to fill the entries.

```
from random import randrange

num1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
num2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

arr1 = [[randrange(10)]*(len(nums2)+1)]*(len(nums1)+1)
arr2 = [[randrange(10) for _ in range(len(nums2)+1)] for _ in range(len(nums1)+1)]

print(arr1)
print(arr2)
```

The output is:

```
[[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
[[7, 4, 2, 4, 0, 3], [7, 5, 1, 0, 1, 7], [4, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1], [2, 3, 6, 2, 6, 7], [6, 6, 6, 0, 3, 3], [0, 4, 5, 0, 6, 6]]
```

You can see that for the `arr1`, it populates every entry with the same number; while for `arr2`, the entries are all truly random. This is because `arr1` is constructed by expanding a list of just one number, which is `[5]` here.